# error: expected primary-expression before ']' token

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm getting the error:

> expected primary-expression before ']' token`

On this line:

```
berakna_histogram_abs(histogram[], textRad);
```

Anybody know why?

```
const int ANTAL_BOKSTAVER = 26;  //A-Z

void berakna_histogram_abs(int histogram[], int antal);

int main() {

   string textRad = "";
   int histogram[ANTAL_BOKSTAVER];

   getline(cin, textRad);

   berakna_histogram_abs(histogram[], textRad);
   return 0;
}

void berakna_histogram_abs(int tal[], string textRad){

   int antal = textRad.length();

   for(int i = 0; i < antal; i++){

      if(textRad.at(i) == 'a' || textRad.at(i) == 'A'){
        tal[0] + 1;
      }
   } 
}
```

Comment: This is not proper way to pass table to function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing table to function wrong. You should simply:

```
berakna_histogram_abs(histogram, textRad);
```

What's more you firstly declare:

```
void berakna_histogram_abs(int histogram[], int antal);
```

But than you're trying to define:

```
void berakna_histogram_abs(int tal[], string textRad){}
```

That's way your compiler think that second argument is `int` and not a `string`. Prototype of function should be consistent with declaration.

Answer (score 3):

In main() call of function is wrong:

```
berakna_histogram_abs(histogram[], textRad);
```

should be:

```
berakna_histogram_abs(histogram, textRad);
```

You need `[]` in function declaration only but not at the time of call function.

Comment: changing to that gives me this error: cannot convert 'std::string {aka std::basic_string<char>}' to 'int' for argument '2' to 'void berakna_histogram_abs(int*, int)'|

Comment: @user1207319 The 2nd parameter of declaration of `berakna_histogram_abs`

Answer (score 3):

Your call to the function `berakna_histogram_abs` is wrong in `main()`, it should be :

```
berakna_histogram_abs(histogram, textRad);
//                             ^
```

The `[]` are in the function declaration to indicated that it takes an array, you don't have to use it for the function call.

You have another error :

The prototype of the function `berakna_histogram_abs` is :

```
void berakna_histogram_abs(int histogram[], int antal);
//                                          ^^^
```

before you `main()` definition and

```
void berakna_histogram_abs(int tal[], string textRad){...}
//                                    ^^^^^^
```

Also in your main you are trying to pass a string as argument, so your code should be :

```
void berakna_histogram_abs(int histogram[], string antal);

int main()
{
    // ...
}

void berakna_histogram_abs(int tal[], string textRad){
    //....
}
```

And last thing : try to pass reference or `const` reference instead of value :

```
void berakna_histogram_abs(int tal[], string& textRad)
//                                          ^
```

---

You final code should look like :

```
const int ANTAL_BOKSTAVER = 26;  //A-Z

void berakna_histogram_abs(int histogram[], const string& antal);

int main() {

   string textRad = "";
   int histogram[ANTAL_BOKSTAVER];

   getline(cin, textRad);

   berakna_histogram_abs(histogram, textRad);
   return 0;
}

void berakna_histogram_abs(int tal[], const string& textRad) {

   int antal = textRad.length();

   for(int i = 0; i < antal; i++){

      if(textRad.at(i) == 'a' || textRad.at(i) == 'A'){
        tal[0] + 1;
      }
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

error is in passing `histogram[]`
pass `histogram` only
In parameter you have defined second argument to be `int` but while defining the function you have kept second argument as `string` type
    change initial definition

```
void berakna_histogram_abs(int histogram[], int antal);
```

to

```
void berakna_histogram_abs(int histogram[], string textRad);
```