# Error: expected primary-expression before ']' token in C++

Tags: c++, function, c++98

I'm trying to create something similar to `string.find` with vectors `c++98`, but I can't fix this error. 
I have simplified the code and left only the error.
If I can get help on how to achieve this.

```
#include <iostream>
#define MAX 99999
using namespace std;

int free_pos (int v[]);
int find_line (int v[], int pos);

int main() {
   char text[MAX];
   int loc_key[MAX],start_line[MAX]; //

   for(int i=0; i<free_pos(loc_key);i++) {
       cout << "Line: " << i+1;
       int pos = find_line(start_line[],loc_key[i]); //Here is the error
       for(int j=start_line[pos];j<start_line[pos+1];j++) {
            cout<<text[j];
       }
       cout<<endl;
   }
   return 0;
}

int free_pos (int v[]) {
    for(int i=0;i<MAX;i++){
        if(v[i] == 0)
            return i;
    }
    return 99;
}

int find_line (int v[], int pos) {
    for(int i=0; i<free_pos(v); i++) {
        if(v[i]==pos)
            return v[i];
        if(v[i]< pos)
            return v[i-1];
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expet `start_line[]` to do?

Comment: that has the index of the char that begins each sentence

Comment: I guess you meant `start_line[i]` instead?

Comment: No, i give an array and a pos, and `find_line()` return index when the line starts

Comment: `find_line(start_line[],loc_key[i]);` -> `find_line(start_line,loc_key[i]);`

Comment: YESSSSSSSS thank you :DDDDD

Comment: That looks like a LOT more than "left only the error". Couldn't you trim your main function down to just the line with the error and the variable declarations?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [error: expected primary-expression before '\]' token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18420334/error-expected-primary-expression-before-token)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your both functions

```
int free_pos (int v[]);
int find_line (int v[], int pos);
```

take arrays as an input, but then you try to call `int pos = find_line(start_line[],loc_key[i]);`, which should take the name of an array **only**, as it is the name which is known by the program as an array. You can easier (in my opinion) get it, if you write both of these functions following way:

```
int free_pos (int* v);
int find_line (int* v, int pos);
```

They do the same job as your functions, but you can see that their arguments are: an int pointer *(array)* and an int. Then, calling the function needs only the int pointer, which in your case is `start_line`, and the integer `loc_key[i]`. If you still have problems understanding it, you could read about dynamic memory allocation of arrays, which is done as: `int* arr; arr = new int[your_size];` - I think it is clearer while thinking that way.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int max(int arr[],int n){
maximum=INT_MAX;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
if(arr[i]>maximum){
maximum=arr[i]}}
return maximum;}

int main(){
int size;
cin>>size;
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
cin>>arr[i]}
cout<<max(arr,size);
return 0;}
```

Comment: 1. ***Never*** recommend the use of `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` in an answer on Stack Overflow; read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31816095/10871073) and then replace that line with the relevant **standard** headers. 2. Add some indentation and decent formatting to your code. 3. Add an explanation as to why/how your code fixes the OP's problem.